# RFM69: Can't Get Anything Out the Antenna

Tags: python, python-3.x, spi

I can read and write any register in the RFM69, but I cannot get it to transmit through the antenna and I suspect it's my lack of understanding of configuration. I have an SDR that I'm using as a spectrum analyzer. I think it's working because I can see other frequencies nearby 915MHz, but not mine. Can someone tell me if my code is lacking?

```
#intended for testing transmitter with spectrum analyzer

import spidev
import time
SPI_BUS = 0
SPI_SS = 0
SPI_CLOCK = 2000000 #Mhz
spi = spidev.SpiDev(SPI_BUS, SPI_SS)
spi.max_speed_hz = SPI_CLOCK
rx = spi.xfer([0x81,0x0c]) #TX mode
i = 1
while True:
    rx = spi.xfer([0x80,0x55]) #address and data
    time.sleep(1)
    print(i)
    i = i+1
spi.close()
```